# Unrecognized authentication type when doing an Auth to Exchange from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exchange-server

I'm getting this error when trying to authenticate with Exchange Server from Ruby on Rails:

> 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication
>   type

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "x.x.x.x",
  :port                 => 25,
  :user_name            => "xxdomain\xxuser",
  :password             => "xxxxxx",
  :authentication       => :login,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations of configuration settings, including changing the settings to use "plain" authentication, adding the domain, setting enable_starttls_auto to true, false, and removing it entirely, removing the port.  Nothing has worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [Cannot get ActionMailer working with MS Exchange via SMTP][1]. It helped me to fix my problem.
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523348/cannot-get-actionmailer-working-with-ms-exchange-via-smtp/12503809#12503809

Answer (score 7):

The below is from link:

[Rails and Exchange Email Auth](http://www.breckenedge.com/configuration-of-ruby-on-rails-actionmailer-for-microsoft-exchange-smtp)

1) Add the **ruby-ntlm** gem to your Gemfile and run **bundle install**.

2) Add the **NTLM SMTP** library to your **config/environment.rb** file.

```
# Load the rails application
  require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
  require 'ntlm/smtp'
# Initialize the rails application
  RailsApp::Application.initialize!
```

3) Set up your environment file to authenticate with NTLM.

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address => '<your-email-server>',
 :domain => '<your-domain>',
 :user_name => '<your-username>',
 :password => '<your-unencrypted-password>',
 :port => 25,
 :authentication => :ntlm
```

****replace values with you own***

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Please fix the link. It is death