# Rails action mailer didn't work on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am trying to send emails via action mailer. I have the same config for production and for development:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'ee.ex.my_domain.net',
    port:                 465,
    domain:               'my_domain',
    user_name:            'email@my_mail.com',
    password:             'my_pass',
    authentication:       :ntlm,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

The only difference between development and production config is the host. For production I use an existing url, on my local machine it works ok but when I try it on the server I got this error:

```
Net::SMTPSyntaxError (504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type)
```

I have had this error before on my local machine but I changed the authentication to `:ntml` and it works fine.

**UPDATE**

tried in server console (code from ntlm gem github page)

```
require 'ntlm/smtp'
smtp = Net::SMTP.new('smtp.example.com')
smtp.start('localhost.localdomain', 'Domain\\User', 'Password', :ntlm) do |smtp|
  smtp.send_mail(mail_body, from_addr, to_addr)
end
```

but have the same error

Comment: Is your dev machine a windows box and your production server a *nix box?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get ActionMailer working with MS Exchange via SMTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523348/cannot-get-actionmailer-working-with-ms-exchange-via-smtp)

Comment: @diego.greyrobot both server and dev are ubuntu linux machines